# load content into table cells based on multiple, different ids at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to ask for help in the following scenario:
I have an SQL query result in a PHP array, containing profileids, names, etc. These profileids are not static, they are coming from SQL. (can not be hardcoded into the javascript)

I would like to query the givedata.php for additional data for all members and load them into the corresponding cells of the table when I check a checkbox. On uncheck event I would like to empty all corresponding cells. I think I need a kind of foreach cycle in jquery. I have only one checkbox, this single event should handle all the 50 queries against the givedata.php.

givedata.php:

```
<?php
//stupid example
echo "You requested".$_REQUEST['profid']."put this to the appropriate row";
?>
```

index.php:

```
<?php
//ab3x is the profileid
$members[‘ab3x’][‘profileid']=“ab3x";
$members[‘ab3x’][‘name']="john";
$members['ab3x'][’score']=1000;
//...
$members['cssd’][‘name']="doe";
$members[‘cssd'][’score’]=2000;
?>
...
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#loadbox").change(function () {

    <?php
    foreach($members as $member)
        {
        $php_array[]=$member[‘profileid’];
        }
    $js_array = json_encode($php_array);
    echo "var javascript_array = ". $js_array . ";\n";
    ?>      

    //What should come here in order to call the givedata.php for 
    //all profids and load the content into the appropriate cells 
    //$( “.profid_ab3x" ).html( data );
    //$( “.profid_cssd" ).html( data );

    });
)}
...
<input type='checkbox' name='load' id='loadbox' value='no'>
...    
<table>
    <?php
        //there are 50 members
        foreach($members as $member){
        echo "<tr>
                <td>”.$member[’name']."</td>
                <td id='profid_".$member[‘profileid’].”’> **HERE COMES THE DYNAMIC CONTENT**  </td>
            </tr>”;
        }
     ?>
</table>
```

**EDITED, added php array to js array Based on Cam’s idea**

Comment: Hae you thought about returning the array into a javascript array using the encode, then using javascript to do the rest of what you are trying to do. Just a simple starter idea.

Comment: @Cam unfortunately I have a very little knowledge on Javascript, but it is a good starting idea. I hope I implemented it correctly

Comment: What I would do is console.log(javascript_array); to see what is returned in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay,

First thing you'll want is the  givedata.php to return a json that should be handled by the javascript, and then return all the data that is queried to you via GET parameters, I'm thinking something like

```
<?php

header("Content-type: application/json");

$json_response = array();

foreach($_GET["id"] as $id){
  array_push($json_response, array( "id" => $id, "data" => get_member_data($id)));
}


echo json_encode($json_response);

?>
```

Wich should return an array with all the corresponding data in json to be parsed by the browser.
You'll also need your checkbox in the html:

```
<input type="checkbox" onchange="check_change(this);">
```

And your javascript to look something like this:

```
function check_change(check){
    if(check.checked){
        loadCells();
    }else{
        deleteCells();
    }
}

function loadCells(){
    $.ajax({
        url:"givedata.php",
        data: javascriptArray,
        success: function(membersData){

            var dataCell;

            for(var i = 0; i < membersData.length; i++){
                dataCell = $(".dataCell #" + membersData.id);
                //do what you must to show the member data
            }
        }
    });
}

function deleteCells(){
    $(".dataCell").each( function(cell){
        //do what you must to clear the data
    });
}
```

Assuming that each dataCell has the .dataCell class and an id with the member Id.

Also, i'm concerned about this line:

```
 $php_array[]=$member[‘profileid’];
```

The proper way to create an array and append elements to it is by instansiating it, and then call [array_push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php), like this:

```
$php_array = array();
array_push($php_array,$element_to_push);
```

Comment: I will try it tonight and get back to you with a solution mark. Thank you. Interesting, you solve it with one big request. I was thinking in 50 small requests. But if works credits, will go.

Answer (score 0):

Final solution based on Sacha’s idea. thx.

WARNING! My knowledge is little on Javascript! Look through before copy paste. It works for me. Maybe someone comes and edits it.

get_chests.php

```
array_push($json_response, array( "id" => $reqprofileid, "data" => $str ));
echo json_encode($json_response);
```

index.php

```
$('#ladakbutton').change(function() {
    if(this.checked != true){
    deleteCells();
    }
if(this.checked == true){
    loadCells();
    }
});


function loadCells(){
    <?php
    $js_array = json_encode($php_array);
    echo "var jsarray = ". $js_array . ";\n";
    ?>
    var data_str = jsarray.join(",");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        url:"includes/get_chests.php",
        data:{
            ids: data_str
            },
        success: function(membersData){
            $(".ladak").show();
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < membersData.length; i++) {
                $('#ladak'+membersData[i].id).html(membersData[i].data);
            }
        }
    });
}
function deleteCells(){
    $('.ladak').empty();
    $(".ladak").hide();
 }
```

the button

```
 <input type="checkbox" id='ladakbutton’>
```

the table

```
<?php
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td class='ladak'" id='ladak".$member['profileid']."' colspan=\"5\”>”;
?>
```